# Given $A = \Sigma\lambda uu^H$. $A = -A^H$. Prove $\lambda$ is imaginary

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A = \Sigma\lambda uu^H$. and $A = -A^H$. Prove $\lambda$ is pure imaginary. (Btw, $u$ are orthonormal vector, don't know how to write here in math-stackexchange with the ^)

I've two proofs I've thought of, I'll give one of them here, I want to know if it is correct.

$A = \Sigma\lambda uu^H$

$-A^H = -\Sigma\lambda ^- uu^H$

Thus, can I say from $A = -A^H$,($\lambda\Sigma uu^H = -\lambda ^-\Sigma uu^H$)  that $\lambda = -\lambda^-$, Thus $\lambda$ is imaginary.

The other proof is with $<Au,u>$ and to move from there which I know is correct. (and using $Au = \lambda u$)

Comment: $A^H$ is Hermitian conjugate?

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes. $A$ here is anti-symmetric. Thus its anti Hermitian because of how the spectral of $A$ is defined.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ intended as a sum? If so, a sum over what?

Comment: @semiclassical Sigma is from i=1 to n.

Comment: Are $\lambda$ and $u$ also supposed to have those subscripts? If so, then your first proof isn't valid since you can't pull $\lambda$ out as an overall constant.

Comment: Are you sure that I cant pull lambda out of the signma?!